# "500: directline:postActivity"

Tags: c#

I have created a sample Luis bot, I have tried for intent detection I have no errors in Bot it is running successfully in the browser. But I am getting an error in the emulator as 
" 500:Directline.postActivity". I have rechecked the path for ngrok and also I have checked all my code with no errors. but still, I am getting the same error can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Looks like you have an http connection.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to debug issue.  Is you have an app that work then compare working sniffer results with non-working results.

Comment: Please see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)